# Splines Animated by Sound - Animation Nodes

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation-nodes, baking, audio, splines

I've just made the change from Blender 2.79 to 2.81a. I've also updated my Animation Nodes to 2.1.4. Both are installed and working as expected except for the Sound Baking function in AN. Some Googling revealed that the Sound Baking functionality has been deprecated. Since I'm only at a beginner level with AN, I'm at a loss for how to redesign the set up for this change.

My project files give me animated splines for audio visualizations that look like this (rendered in Cycles):[image: rendered image (PNG) - output sample]

Each frequency range is represented by one of the lines. To achieve this, here is the original node setup:

[image: AN Step 1][image: AN Step 2][image: AN Step 3]

The workflow was to first bake the sound, then run the render to a folder. I'd then load them into a VSE track in a new file with the original sound file and other elements.

In 2.1.4, there are two nodes that are no longer available: the Evaluate Sound (Step 2) and the Bake Sound (Step 3) nodes. I've tried replacing the Evaluate Sound node with either of the available Sound nodes, but they don't connect (yellow nodule is on the output side only). I've also tried connecting the new node Sound From Sequence directly into the Sound nodule of the Invoke Subprogram node, but that doesn't do anything either.

Any help / guidance would be very much appreciated, though I'd love to know the why as much as the how so I can improve my understanding of AN.

Answer (score 0):

The working solution was to use BOTH the Sound From Sequence and Sound Spectrum nodes in place of the Evaluate Sound node. Since AN no longer requires baking to animate a mesh to sound, the Bake Sound node I could just delete entirely. Step 1 remained the same, and here's a shot of the updated Step 2:

[image]